# Computing unknown matrix norm

Tags: matrices, algorithms, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

Suppose that we have a unknown vector norm but there is a machine that get a vector and correctly tell us the norm of the vector. Is there any algorithm to compute the matrix norm corresponding to this vector norm? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your question is more general, but this question and the answers are relevant to your question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37913/how-do-i-calculate-the-p-norm-of-a-matrix

Comment: I would guess you have in mind the *operator norm* of a square matrix corresponding to the (unknown but computable) vector norm, i.e. $$\sup_{v\neq 0} \frac{||Av||}{||v||}$$