# Hadamard's inequality proof validation

Tags: inequality

I saw proof regarding Hadamard's inequality written by Ben Grossmann, and I was confused about the first equality in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5vUb.png). I think it should be
$$
\|a_j\|^2_2 \leq (\sum_{i=1}^j |r_{ij}| \|q_j\|_2)^2 
$$
since the triangle inequality of norms. Thus, the proof fails.

Sorry, I forgot to attach the link to his proof https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2301769